# Alpine Linux: fatal: privsep_preauth: preauth child terminated by signal 31

Tags: ssh, alpine

I have some containers with Alpine Linux. Yesterday I updated two of them from v3.8 to v3.10. OpenSSH server was upgraded from `7.7_p1-r4` to `8.0_p1-r0`. After that, the client is unable to login.

Note: Using default sshd configuration, nothing edited.

This is the client log:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.100.200 [10.0.100.200] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.0.100.200" from file "/home/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ef:c3:27:6b:30:9b:a9:dc:d3:f7:f8:fb:5f:a4:85:8c
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.0.100.200" from file "/home/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '10.0.100.200' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
tester@10.0.100.200's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 51 padlen 13 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.0.100.200 ([10.0.100.200]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

---

This is the log at the server:

```
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 248
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Connection from 10.0.100.1 port 53759 on 10.0.100.200 port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
debug2: Network child is on pid 31051
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 22:22 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 22/22 [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: hostkey proof signature 0x7f128dbdd4e0(101)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user tester service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 248
debug3: auth_shadow_acctexpired: today 18173 sp_expire -1 days left -18174
debug3: account expiration disabled
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for tester [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 1.154ms, delaying 7.514ms (requested 8.667ms) [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user tester service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=tester devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.031ms, delaying 8.636ms (requested 8.667ms) [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user tester service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12 [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 13 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 12
debug3: auth_shadow_pwexpired: today 18173 sp_lstchg 18172 sp_max 99999
debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 13
Accepted password for tester from 10.0.100.1 port 53759 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: tester has been authenticated by privileged process
debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 26
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_get_keystate: GOT new keys
debug3: mm_auth_password: user authenticated [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 10.636ms, delaying 6.699ms (requested 8.667ms) [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 52 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 26 [preauth]
debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
privsep_preauth: preauth child terminated by signal 31
debug1: do_cleanup
```

I have seen several similar bug reports but most of them are pretty old. Some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255696/sshd-preauth-child-terminated-by-signal-31) suggests to add `UsePrivilegeSeparation` option, but it has been [deprecated](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.5). If I go back to use `7.7` version by setting the 3.8 repository and uninstalling/installing openssh, all works fine.

As I will keep updating containers, I would like to know what I can do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After encountering what appears to be the same issue on a Debian box after upgrading a stack of packages, I finally came across https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/9984, which seems to indicate a current bug in OpenSSH 8.0p1. Fix was PR'd as https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/11780, and has been merged. Not sure what release the fix is in (if it's even released yet), and not able to ssh into my box to fix it even if it **is** fixed!

Comment: Thank you. It seems the [patch has been commited for Alpine Linux](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/commit/7247aa072216f582045f013f1166b122be0967bd). Not sure when It will hit the release version. I can confirm that the current openssl version in alpine is 1.1.1d and the kernel in my host is old: 3.13.0 (in another server, which has the 4.15, its working fine). My suggestion is try to upgrade your host/kernel if possible.